# Apple Health is not storing samples from device

Tags: ios, iphone, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I'm trying to use Apple Health as an alternative to bluetooth for a fitness app. On one of my devices connecting a heart rate monitor to the phone through settings results in Apple Health populating with heart rate samples marked with the bluetooth icon to indicate that it is from a device. On almost every other device though the samples never show up unless I restart the phone. Then after some time it stops working again and needs another restart. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you mean check the device error logs, I don't see anything that looks obviously related to health. If you mean check the XCode error logs, then this is not a problem with my app so there is nothing to check.